# error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: centos, electron, centos7, node-modules

I'm using CentOS 7 x64, npm 5.6.0, node v9.5.0. I executed `npm i electron` in my console and it completed the installation without any errors.

However, when I type in `electron` in my console, I get the following error

> /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've looked around on the internet trying to find a solution, but I couldn't find one for my specific OS. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

I would greatly appreciate any comments/answers.
Thank you.